# How can I make a button that uploads a emoji to input box?

Tags: html, textbox, emoji

So, I'm making a chatting app, and I was wondering how to make a button that uploads a GIF or an emoji to the html text box. Like in google hangouts, there is a button that is a little face, and when you click on it, you can select an emoji.

[image: The Emoji Button]

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: there's 3rd party libraries that will help with that

Comment: "I'm making a chatting app" - you haven't told us what platform you're using - we can't help you without knowing that. And if you say "HTML+JS" you still need to tell us if it's Electron, HTA, localhost-only, or public website and what you're using for state-persistence and so on....

Comment: sorry, I'm using node js, ejs, html and js.

Comment: I found this: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Emoji-Picker-For-Text-Fields.html